# Disowning child from parent process

Tags: process, jenkins, disown

If `$PID_PARENT` launched `$PID_CHILD`, how can I detach (`disown`?) `$PID_CHILD` from `$PID_PARENT` so that, when I kill `$PID_PARENT`, `$PID_CHILD` keeps running like nothing happened?

Concretely, my `$PID_PARENT` is the process running `Jenkins` (or the `Java` process that runs the server that runs Jenkins) and `$PID_CHILD` is a *really long* job that I don't want to have to restart after restarting Jenkins (which is needed for some maintenance). Essentially, I want to stop Jenkins but not stop the long job it started and I know both PIDs.

**UPDATE 1:** I found out about `disown` and tried from a login shell (so not the parent PID shell):

```shell
disown $PID_CHILD
```

but got

```
-bash: disown: 13924: no such job
```

The `$PID_CHILD` correct and doing

```shell
ps -o ppid= $PID_CHILD
```

returns `$PID_PARENT`

**UPDATE 2:** As per @Rui's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452267/23944), I made a temporary hack job in Jenkins that only runs from the parent shell this time:

```shell
disown 13924
```

but still got

```
disown: 13924: no such job
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to have the child process disassociate itself from the parent. This will [require suitable code in the child process](https://perldoc.pl/perlipc#Complete-Dissociation-of-Child-from-Parent), or a wrapper script that performs the disassociation before executing the real code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
die "Usage: $0 command [args ..]\n" unless @ARGV;
# diassociate this process (some folks also do a double-fork thing)
use POSIX "setsid";
chdir("/") || die "can't chdir to /: $!";
open( STDIN,  "< /dev/null" ) || die "can't read /dev/null: $!";
open( STDOUT, "> /dev/null" ) || die "can't write to /dev/null: $!";
defined( my $pid = fork() ) || die "can't fork: $!";
exit if $pid;    # non-zero now means I am the parent
( setsid() != -1 ) || die "Can't start a new session: $!";
open( STDERR, ">&STDOUT" ) || die "can't dup stdout: $!";
# and replace ourself with whatever we were called with
exec @ARGV;
```

which if saved as `solitary` can be tested via something like:

```
% ./solitary logger greppable
% grep greppable /var/log/system.log
Jun 27 10:52:15 hostn jhqdoe[20966]: greppable
%
```

with the use of `logger(1)` because the standard filehandles were all closed as part of the disassociation. These may need to be redirected elsewhere for your application.

Note that this may not be possible if Jenkins (or systemd or whatever) uses a PID namespace that the process cannot escape no matter how it forks itself, in which case you would need some container-level solution, or to revisit what you're trying to do.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Colombus' egg and the *joys* of systemd.

Comment: boggles my mind there isn't a quick way to do this, which seems like a pretty stock function...

Comment: how do you pass the PID to your script? -- i don't see how you actually set `$pid`

Comment: @amphibient there is no pid to set. Jenkins (or whatever) runs `solitary blah blah blah` where `blah blah blah` is usually what gets run, and `solitary` disassociates (via all those various system calls) then replaces itself with `blah blah blah`. There is a `daemon(3)` call but that may or may not be portable.

Comment: so if there are 7 processes spawned off by Jenkins, they would all get disowned?

Comment: anything run as `solitary ...` will be disowned

Comment: but what is run as solitary ? I have an explicit single process that is owned by another explicit process and I would prefer to explicitly run this switch knowing I am affecting exactly those processes. basically, i do not want to run an ambiguous bag of processes under the assumption it contains only the processes I want to effect...

Comment: run that process as `solitary how your run that process` and it will disassociate itself from the parent. if you cannot do that then you will need to do something else.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to simply do

```
$ disown $PID
```

Then if you terminate your shell session, the process will still be running.

Comment: is `$PID` the PID of the child or the parent ?

Comment: that didn't work, see the update to the OP

Comment: `disown` is a ksh93 extension that is not available in most shells.

Comment: @schily using here it with `bash`

Comment: You may later create a script that uses `/bin/sh` and that does not support it.

Comment: I created a hack jon in Jenkins that only runs `disown 13924` but still got `disown: 13924: no such job`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your `disown` from the shell that called the process. Hence calling from other shell you get the message `no such job`.

To actually disown a process and tell it to ignore the hangup signal, you would do from the shell that called the process:

```
disown -h $PID
```

From disown help:

> $ disown --help
>       disown: disown [-h] [-ar] [jobspec ... | pid ...]
>           Remove jobs from current shell.
>
> ```
>     Removes each JOBSPEC argument from the table of active jobs.  Without
>     any JOBSPECs, the shell uses its notion of the current job.
>
>     Options:
>       -a    remove all jobs if JOBSPEC is not supplied
>       -h    mark each JOBSPEC so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the
>                     shell receives a SIGHUP
>       -r    remove only running jobs
>
>     Exit Status:
>     Returns success unless an invalid option or JOBSPEC is given.
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to emulate `disown from the shell that called the process` from the login shell that is not the shell that called the process (kind of like `sudo` does anything as a user)?

Comment: @amphibient I think not, but let´s wait if someone says something in contrary or has a clever idea.

Comment: I am pretty surprised there isn't a ready way to do this, seems like a pretty standard function...

Answer (score 1):

When creating a background process that persists after a Jenkins build completes, you will need to watch out for the [Jenkins Process Tree Killer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller). When a build exits, the process tree killer attempts to kill all processes related to that build, even if the processes have been disowned from the build process and are no longer child processes of the build process.

There are instructions in the link above for how to disable the process tree killer for particular jobs or for Jenkins as a whole.