# Script dies when parent process is terminated

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

I have a .NET Core service running on a Debian 9, let's call it MyService. At some point this service is running a bash script `update.sh` using `Process.Start()` with `ShellExecute=true`.

This script basically runs `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`.

During package upgrade, MyService process is terminated: update script is terminated as well and `apt-get upgrade` is killed as well, leaving inconsistent packages that must be fixed manually.

What I want is that `update.sh` is NOT terminated when MyService is terminated.

I tried splitting `update.sh` in 2 parts, the first running the second in different ways; I tried starting `update2.sh` with `setsid` and `nohup` but I always get same result.
I tried to execute `update2.sh` script in a new bash shell with `/bin/bash /c "update2.sh"`, same result.

How do I run a script started from a binary and completely detach from binary process, so I can kill binary while script keeps running?

Here's my environment. MyService is a binary running as a service. `update.sh` is started by MyService.

**.NET Core code to start shell script, inside MyService binary:**

```
var process = new Process();
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // to avoid [defunct] sh processes
process.StartInfo.FileName = "/opt/myservice/update.sh";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit(10000);
if (process.HasExited)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Exit code: " + process.ExitCode);
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Child process still running after 10 seconds");
}
```

**update.sh:**

```
nohup /opt/myservice/update2.sh > /opt/myservice/update.log &
systemctl stop MyService
```

**update2.sh:**

```
apt-get update >> /opt/myservice/update.log
apt-get -y install --only-upgrade myservice-1.0 >> /opt/myservice/update.log
```

`update2.sh` is never executed because it's terminated when MyService is terminated by `update.sh`.

`update.sh` returns code 143, it seems it has been killed.

```
2018-08-16 14:46:14.5215|Running update script: /opt/myservice/update.sh
2018-08-16 14:46:14.5883|Update script /opt/myservice/update.sh returned: 143
```

**UPDATE**

I tried following approaches, thanks for suggestions:

- setsid
- disown
- nohup
- screen
- tmux
- unshare

Every approach has same result, termination of all spawned processes.
I suspect this is a .NET Core "feature".

**UPDATE 2**

I discovered that `systemctl stop MyService` by default explicitly kills all spawned processes by a service.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898077/systemd-systemctl-stop-aggressively-kills-subprocesses

If I add `KillMode=process` to service descriptor, update script is not terminated when service is terminated.

There is **NO WAY** to escape from PID space for a service started by `systemctl`. Every technique used, included the one in accepted answer, does not generate a separate process. Every spawned process is always killed by `systemctl stop MyService` unless `KillMode=process` is specified.

I ended up creating a separate service `MyServiceUpdater`: this service runs the plain updater script without any forking. Since PID space is different, everything works as expected. That was a long ride.

MyServiceUpdater example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Your Service Updater
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/update/script/updatescript.sh
ExecStopPost=
TimeoutStopSec=30
StandardOutput=null
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/service/directory/
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452262/disowning-child-from-parent-process/452286#452286 is one way to "completely detach from" a process

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried perl script, same result. Could be ".NET Core runtime uses a PID namespace that the process cannot escape no matter how it forks itself" as described in page you suggested.

Comment: It seems that .NET Core application kills all spawned processes on termination, regardless any strategy I take.

Comment: Fighting the same problem with my upgrader script. Possible to post the unit file for `MyServiceUpdater` ?

Comment: @Danny I added the updater service file. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Centos 7 test system via

```
$ sudo rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm
$ sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

which results in `dotnet-sdk-2.1-2.1.400-1.x86_64` being installed then with the test code

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace myApp {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var process = new Process();
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // to avoid [defunct] sh processes
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "/var/tmp/foo";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit(10000);
            if (process.HasExited) {
                Console.WriteLine("Exit code: " + process.ExitCode);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Child process still running after 10 seconds");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a shell script as `/var/tmp/foo` a `strace` stalls out and shows that `/var/tmp/foo` is run through `xdg-open` which on my system does...I'm not sure what, it seems a needless complication.

```
$ strace -o foo -f dotnet run
Child process still running after 10 seconds
^C
$ grep /var/tmp/foo foo
25907 execve("/usr/bin/xdg-open", ["/usr/bin/xdg-open", "/var/tmp/foo"], [/* 37 vars */] <unfinished ...>
...
```

a simpler solution is to simply `exec` a program that in turn can be a shell script that does what you want, which for .NET requires not using the shell:

```
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

with this set the `strace` shows that `/var/tmp/foo` is being run via a (much simpler) `execve(2)` call:

```
26268 stat("/var/tmp/foo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=37, ...}) = 0
26268 access("/var/tmp/foo", X_OK)      = 0
26275 execve("/var/tmp/foo", ["/var/tmp/foo"], [/* 37 vars */] <unfinished ...>
```

and that .NET refuses to exit:

```
$ strace -o foo -f dotnet run
Child process still running after 10 seconds
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
```

because `foo` replaces itself with something that ignores most signals (notably not `USR2`, or there is always `KILL` (but avoid using that!)):

```
$ cat /var/tmp/foo
#!/bin/sh
exec /var/tmp/stayin-alive
$ cat /var/tmp/stayin-alive
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Sys::Syslog;
for my $s (qw(HUP INT QUIT PIPE ALRM TERM CHLD USR1)) {
   $SIG{$s} = \&shandle;
}
openlog( 'stayin-alive', 'ndelay,pid', LOG_USER );
while (1) {
    syslog LOG_NOTICE, "oh oh oh oh oh stayin alive";
    sleep 7;
}
sub shandle {
    syslog LOG_NOTICE, "nice try - @_";
}
```

## daemonize

With [a process that disassociates itself from the parent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452286/128228) and a shell script that runs a few commands (hopefully equivalent to your intended `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`)

```
$ cat /var/tmp/a-few-things
#!/bin/sh
sleep 17 ; echo a >/var/tmp/output ; echo b >/var/tmp/output
```

we can modify the .NET program to run `/var/tmp/solitary /var/tmp/a-few-things`

```
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "/var/tmp/solitary";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/var/tmp/a-few-things";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

which when run causes the .NET program to exit fairly quickly

```
$ dotnet run
Exit code: 0
```

and, eventually, the `/var/tmp/output` file does contain two lines written by a process that was not killed when the .NET program when away.

You probably should save the output from the APT commands somewhere, and may also need something so that two (or more!) updates are not 
trying to be run at the same time, etc. This version does not stop for questions and ignores any `TERM` signals (`INT` may also need to be ignored).

```
#!/bin/sh
trap '' TERM
set -e
apt-get --yes update
apt-get --yes upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. May I ask you a test? Try to kill .NET Core foo binary inside a-few-things script. Check if a-few-things script continue execution. Consider that in my scenario, `foo` is a service running in background, killed by `apt-get upgrade` during package upgrade.

Comment: Instead of 17 seconds, just wait 5 seconds then kill `foo`. Then do something else that produces output. You should also add a `Console.ReadLine()` after process execution in C# code. What happens?

Comment: kill `foo` how? various signals, if necessary, could be ignored or handled in various ways via calls detailed in `signal(2)`

Comment: I don't know exactly. In your opinion, how `apt-get upgrade` kills a previously running daemon when updating to the new version? Inside .deb package I have prerm script running `systemctl stop MyService`. Does this perform a KILL?

Comment: does it? use `sysdig` and see what signals are sent to what, then use that information to block or change the signal handling as necessary

Comment: This is what .NET Core MyService receives upon `systemctl stop` : `5722 01:50:56.367366640 6 systemd (1) > kill pid=25704(MyService) sig=15(SIGTERM) 
5723 01:50:56.367377180 6 systemd (1) < kill res=0 
5724 01:50:56.367378467 6 systemd (1) > kill pid=25704(MyService) sig=18(SIGCONT)`

Comment: so ignore the TERM signal during the update

Answer (score 2):

Use crontab (or at) (not mono/.net) to schedule tasks.

Normal options;

- nohup my.sh &
- screen -dm -S my my.sh
- tmux new -d -s my my.sh
- service my start / systemctl start my
- Ctrl+Z, bg, disown

Comment: Crontab: it's not designed to run one task once. nohup: tried and it's terminated. I would like to use base installation without additional tools/daemons. I know I could use at.

Comment: at has another issue, it doesn't run as root. If I schedule a task as root, it's not executed as root. So it doesn't work in my scenario.

Comment: `update.sh` MUST be executed by .NET Core service because it's application feature autoupdate, triggered from remote command. Inside `update.sh` I can do whatever I want to perform update.

Comment: Your tmux command line is wrong. Tried 1,2,3, no luck, they all behave the same. systemctl is unrelated because update script is not a service, can't run like this. Last one is interactive and unrelated in my context.

Comment: @Ghigo i fixed the tmux example, you can make your script a service by copying it to /etc/init.d . All interactive things can be scripted.

Comment: Tried disown, still no luck. I think this is a "feature" of .NET framework. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Been battling the exact same thing myself.

One solution I've found is to use `systemd-run`, which essentially creates a transient one-time service to execute an arbitary command.
However for it to work it seems to require that you specify the `-r` (remain-after-exit) argument. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html for more documentation.

For example:

```
var process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "systemd-run",
        Arguments = "-r sleep 90",
        RedirectStandardOutput = false,
        RedirectStandardError = false,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    },
};
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Start();
```